# how can I pass an object from one component to another in angular

Tags: angular, binding, components

I have a component with different modal and in each modal I must show the information of each property, this information is in another component. I have that information in a vector of objects. From what I read I must use Binding between components (father and son) the doubt that I have is how is an object that I must pass to the other component and then show their data, how could I do it? I must declare an object type real @input and how would you do to bindear the whole object from one component to another? what I want to do is show the values of that object in the template of that component.

Here is a sample of what I have:

I have this class that has been the object of which I speak:

```js
export class Inmueble {
  nombre: string="";
  id: string="";
  baño: number=0;
  estacionamiento: number=0;
  metro: number=0;
  precio: number=0;
  fotos: string[]=[];

}
```

I import that class into COMPONENT1 where I fill it with data through a request to an API. What I want is (after filling that object) to pass it to the COMPONENT2, what I was thinking was to do this in COMPONENT2:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

class {
  @Input vector: inmueble[];
}
```

but how do I do for the object filled from COMPONENT1 to COMPONENT2? in the examples I see that they do it for a single variable like this: [variable] = "value", but this would be a vector and I think that doing it line by line would be very unimportant. What I want to achieve with this is to show that object in the COMPONENT2 template. Thanks to everyone beforehand. Regards!

Edit:

Component 1:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: `<p>Model: {{prueba.nombre}} </p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, Input {
  @Input() prueba: Inmueble;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  

  }




}
```

Component 2:

```js
 <app-modal [prueba]="inmuebles[0]" > </app-modal>
```

I assign real estate [0] since in this component I have an array of properties, so in theory I would be assigning a property to a property.

is showing me this error:

```js
ERROR in ./src/app/modal/modal.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './<p>Model: {{prueba.nombre}} </p>' in '/home/julian/Seaconfiable/src/app/modal'
```

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood it correctly, you need to pass complex data object across components.

You can easily do this using `property binding` from parent component to child component as an `@Input` property as

```
 @Input() vector: inmueble[];
```

A sample created at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-object-passing-between-components

Comment: hello friend, I'm doing it as it is but it does not work for me, will it be because I have a real estate vector that in your example would be a Car vector? that is, in COMPONENT1 I have a vector of Car. In the binding I could do this: <hello [car]="car[0]"></hello>   ??

Comment: @JulianProg by vector, you mean array of estate? Like estate[]?

Comment: I mean an array of real estate (In your example would be an array of Car), edit my question so you see my code and the error that is showing me.

Comment: I have updated my stackblitz to have an array of car. @JulianProg

Comment: I'm seeing my code and yours and I do not see any difference, I'm doing it just like you, you saw the code in my question and the error that is showing me? which may be?